# How to check if locations are within map bounds on server with Google Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-functions, google-maps-markers

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Function on Firebase Functions creates geocodes an address
- There are a set of results that I want to verify are within the
  bounds of the map

**Import FB Functions and Admin, Initialize**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

**Handle CORS during testing**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});
```

**Google Maps Clients - google-maps-services-js**

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'xxxxxxx'
});
```

The main issue is that I want to query the db and have the backend check if the results are within the bounds of the map, filter the results down and respond. I don't want to get all the results and filter them on the frontend.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


  // CORS Container - allow all request origins
  corsHandler(request, response, () => {

    // Retrieve listings data from DB
    return admin.database().ref('/listings').once('value').then(snapshots => {

      // Geocode an address.
      return googleMapsClient.geocode({
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'

      }, function(err, response) {

        if (!err) {

          let res = response.json.results;
          let lat = res[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
          let lng = res[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];

          // Want to get the bounds here
          // let bounds = ???

          let results = [];

          // Filter snapshot results
          snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {

            // Get snapshot's position
            const position = snapshot.val().position;

            // Check if snapshot position is within map's bounds
            if (bounds.contains(position)) {
              results.push(snapshot);
            }

          });

          return response.status(200).send({
            "data": bounds
          });

        }
      });


    }).catch(e => {

      return response.status(422).send({
        "data": e
      });

    });

  });

});
```

It's easy to get the map's bounds and check if a location object is within bounds on the frontend:

```
map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition());
```

Struggling to get this working on the backend with Firebase Functions.

Comment: What is the structure of your position in database? Geocoding api returns bounds as object not array and the key for them is name.

Comment: It would like this --> position : {lat: 43.7567534}, {lng: -79.31590169999998}. It works for me on the frontend like so `bounds.contains(position)`

Answer (score 0):

may be try

```
  return response.status(200).send({
    "data": results
  });
```

instead

```
  return response.status(200).send({
    "data": bounds
  });
```